# Change a lookup column's width without influencing other text boxes

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, lookup-column

I wanted my lookup column to be larger therefore I added a web part with code to my NewForm:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('select[title="Relation possible values"]').width(500); 
        $('select[title="Relation selected values"]').width(300); 
     });
</script>
```

My problem is now that all of the text boxes are that large. I tried to set their width as well but that doesn't seem to change anything.

What should I do?

Comment: You are doing something wrong. it should take only the width of the title defined. Try once with ID. Also make sure you have not made the parent element width as Auto. Check in developer tool before going for actual code change. it will give a better view.

Comment: Using this code, worked fine for me. Can you provide more information?

Comment: Hello, 
I tried it on other forms and sometimes all text boxes are getting bigger, sometimes just the one defined :/ I tried with ID (the id defined in the SPD code) which didn't work and none of the elements have auto width

Comment: What do you mean with developer tool?

Comment: Also.. one of the text boxes has the normal width (300px) and two of the others are getting larger (as large as I set the Relation box). I checked the SPD code and it looked the same for both :/

Comment: developer tool is the one in the browser. once when you press f12 from your keyboard you get the console to try your javascript directly. Since two are getting larger. those two are certainly in the same row (tr or td) as your lookup field. and since the row width is set to auto, the others inside it is returning the same width. press f12 and check your FORM structure and identify the width to be increased

Comment: all of the textboxes under the defined one are getting bigger (and yes they are in the same row).. but they have a fixed width, where would I see if the width was set to auto?

Comment: Also: I can make the other columns smaller or wider but cannot change the two that seem to act automatically.. but I cannot find the difference in the code!